# Vue. Change the contents of one slot from another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component with certain slots.

```
    <v-split-container ref="splitContainer" class="panel-panel">
        <template slot="left">
           Test
        </template>
        <template slot="right">
            <router-view></router-view> //Show Compontent A
        </template>
        <template slot="bottom"> //Slot B
            Hello
        </template>
    </v-split-container>
```

Can I, from component A, change the contents of slot B by calling a function inside the component?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it with [Scoped Slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots). I have created an example for you how to do it. Please not that I am using `v-slots`([Some context here](https://vuedose.tips/tips/new-v-slot-directive-in-vue-js-2-6-0/)) only usable from vue v2.6.

Please take a look at the code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2030jo20j0?fontsize=14

> Child Component

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <div>
          <slot name="msgSlot">{{msg}}</slot>
        </div>
        <br>
        <slot name="bottom" :updateMsg="updateMsg"></slot>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      data: () => ({
        msg: "Default Message"
      }),
      methods: {
        updateMsg(text) {
          this.msg = text;
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

> Parent Component

```html
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <HelloWorld>
          <template v-slot:msgSlot></template>
          <template v-slot:bottom="{updateMsg}">
            <input type="text" v-model="msg">
            <button @click="updateMsg(msg)">Change Msg</button>
          </template>
        </HelloWorld>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      data: () => ({
        msg: ""
      }),
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: And if you need to add a complex text, and components?

Comment: You should still able to do it. You need to give me a working code example to help you further.